# How can I limit my costs when buying freighters?

Tags: no-mans-sky

Is it like star ships where you should save and search to get the best one you can from the start, because you have to simply abandon your current freighter when getting a new one? Is that even an option? I've only looked at two, but they both had 13 slots and cost roughly the same amount. I'm also guessing there's no way to get free ones like you can with ships?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [No Man's Sky Wiki](http://nomanssky.wikia.com/wiki/Freighters#Storage):

> Freighters have a maximum storage capacity of 48 slots and the first freighters encountered have 13 slots. Once a freighter is purchased, the freighters the player encounters from then on will have 2 additional storage slots and cost about 2.5 million credits more than the last until the cap is reached.

[Another Wiki](http://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Freighter#Upgrading) states similar information:

> Freighters can be upgraded in the same general manner as individual ships, with each upgrade adding a slot or two to what your current freighter contains (cost per upgrade will be roughly 2.5 million units).

The first one will always have 13 slots and there isn't a free one to begin with.  The next one you buy will have 1 to 2 more slots and this continues until the max is reached. The price goes up by about 2.5 million credits each time you buy a new freighter.

Comment: I don't like this answer. That's hundreds of millions of units. :(

Comment: It really is.  I didn't know this information either until you asked this question.  So I say to you - I don't like this question :(

Comment: Weird thing is your link has a picture of a 48 slot freighter costing over 100 million units.  My math with a 13 slot ship costing 7 million (what I saw the two in my game go for) gives me the 48 slot ship costing around 60 million. I wonder if there is more to it?

Comment: I think the proper math would be (estimating here) something like: (48 - 13) * 2.5 Million + 7 million to equal 94.5 million.  Where 48 is the max slots, 13 is the starting slots that you pay 7 million for, and 2.5 million being the rough estimate of how much a new ship cost each time. Since we are estimating, I think seeing a ship with 48 slots that costs around 105 million sounds valid.  However, this does not include how much the ship costs before adding 2.5 million to it.  For example, buying a 46 slot ship would cost roughly 100 million, and a 48 slot one would be another ~102.5 million ☺

Comment: Just to be clear, I wouldn't rely on my math though :D

Comment: You get two slots per upgrade though, so you have to divide the 48-13 by two. Right? The second wiki.you quoted says "1 or 2" though. Hmm. I might just have to make some money and buy some.